# how to show image when writing on the text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to show an image when the user writing on `EditText`,

here the same output when touching the `EditText` :

```
menuH.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                menuH2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                menuH2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  Index.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

So, I need the function that do the same output but when the user writing on the `EditText`,, Thanks on advanced :)

---

Explanation :

look at the picture:

[image]

when the user write sth on the edit text i want to show an image, if we assume (abbruch and ok) are images so i want to show them when writing, but when the user stop writing on the `EditText` and switch to another edit text the image disappear

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, please tell us what you have and what you want in more details.

Comment: ok :) , i will edit my question , Mr @abforce

Comment: You can use `addTextChangedListener` on your edittext. And in `onTextChanged`  you can show your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the TextChangedListener, like :

```
menuH.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // Show your image

            } 

        });
```

Comment: i will try it and tell u